# Placement of objects after a verb

Tags: syntactic-analysis, word-order, grammatical-roles, indirect-objects, dative-alternation

I learned that if we place an indirect object after a direct object, we use to/for to connect. Can we use any other preposition to do the same ?

Example:

> Put the blanket on me.

Here, "me" (indirect object) is placed after blanket (direct object) using on.

Comment: You may not be aware of SE English Language Learners, which seems to me a more appropriate place to post this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an indirect object. [As Grammarly explains,](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/indirect-object/) an indirect object happens when a preposition is not used (e.g. "Give me the ball"). Such a sentence can be rewritten to use a prepositional phrase instead (e.g. "Give the ball to me"), but then the word in question ceases to be an indirect object.

Your sentence just has an ordinary prepositional phrase ("on me"). You couldn't use an indirect object there; you would end up writing "Put me the blanket," which obviously makes no sense.

Comment: What makes a prepositional phrase 'non-ordinary'? Are you saying that 'to' (and perhaps 'for'?) are the only prepositions seen in dative transformations of ditransitive / benefactive verbs?

Comment: By "ordinary" I just mean that in context it cannot be transformed into an indirect object.

Comment: Grammarly is wrong. "Indirect object" is an ill-defined term in English grammar, and if you use it, sometimes it has a preposition and sometimes it doesn't. It depends on whether it undergoes Dative. _Bill gave me the book_ and _Bill gave the book to me_ mean the same, are both grammatical, and have the same constituents, including an indirect object, if you want to use that term.

Comment: @JohnLawler Does the ill-definedness of this term result from its use sometimes for a grammatical/syntactic role and other times for a thematic/semantic role (like beneficiary or recipient)? // Is dative alternation even possible in [“Will you forbid him the house where I know he’s safe?” (Charles Dickens, *Our Mutual Friend*)](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/72814#eid159336734)

Comment: @JohnLawler I disagree; for once Grammarly is right. PPs are not indirect objects, though they are complements of the verb. In "Bill gave the book to me", "me" is complement of the prep "to", not of the verb "gave".

Comment: Well, BillJ disagrees. There you have it.